# Get a key name from nested json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Below is my json

```
{
"corpAPIBankingReq": {
    "Header": {
        "TranID": "1"
    },
    "Body": {
        "CustType": "Corporate",
        "Action_Type": "MultiPayment",
        "Action_Body": {
            "doMultiPaymentCorpReq": {
                "Header": {
                    "TranID": "${=System.currentTimeMillis() + ((int)(Math.random()*1000))}",
                    "Corp_ID": "ZOHO",
                    "Maker_ID": "M001",
                    "Checker_ID": "C001",
                    "Approver_ID": "A002"
                },
                "Body": {
                    "Payment": [
                        {
                            "RefNo": "test1",
                            "Amount": "100",
                            "Debit_TrnParticulars": "AISHWARYA",
                            "Debit_PartTrnRmks": "SESHADRI",
                            "Ben_Acct_No": "1000110010002463",
                            "Ben_TrnParticulars": "FTTEST",
                            "Ben_PartTrnRmks": "ABHIJEET",
                            "Mode_of_Pay": "FT",
                            "Nature_of_Pay": "SALC",
                            "Remarks": "DMR"
                        },
                        {
                            "RefNo": "test10063",
                            "Amount": "5",
                            "Debit_Acct_No": "409000115190",
                            "Debit_Acct_Name": "SACHIN R TENDULKAR",
                            "Debit_IFSC": "RATN0000999",
                            "Debit_Mobile": "9819378393",
                            "Ben_IFSC": "UBIN0556688",
                            "Ben_Acct_No": "8884476527",
                            "Ben_Name": "Sudarshan",
                            "Ben_BankName": "DHANALAXMI-Bank",
                            "Ben_Email": "prabhat.deep1234567wearethebest@naturesports.co.in",
                            "Ben_Mobile": "9696969696",
                            "Mode_of_Pay": "IMPS",
                            "Nature_of_Pay": "MPYMT",
                            "Remarks": "IMPS REQUEST"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Signature": {
                    "Signature": "1234"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the above json I need to find out what is the first child of "Action_Body", here in this case "doMultiPaymentCorpReq". This key will keep on changing dynamically, so I need to find it from it's parent. Then I will use it like

```
if(first child of Action Body is doMultiPaymentCorpReq){
   Do something;
}
else{
   Do something else;
}
```

Can anybody please help how can I find the first element here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in JSON / JS objects there's not really any concept of the "first" child - there's no specification stating what order the keys should be listed or enumerated in. It can't be guaranteed. Is there a set of known key names which may be used? You can use a JS `for (key in obj)` style of loop (note no jQuery required!) to loop the properties of the "Action_body" object and get all the keys, and locate the one you're interested in. It seems odd for the server to produce inconsistent JSON IMO, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find `first item` of your `Action_Body` in your `JSON` and compare value:

```
for (first in obj.corpAPIBankingReq.Body.Action_Body) {
  if (first == 'doMultiPaymentCorpReq') {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

```js
var obj = {
  "corpAPIBankingReq": {
    "Header": {
      "TranID": "1"
    },
    "Body": {
      "CustType": "Corporate",
      "Action_Type": "MultiPayment",
      "Action_Body": {
        "doMultiPaymentCorpReq": {
          "Header": {
            "TranID": "${=System.currentTimeMillis() + ((int)(Math.random()*1000))}",
            "Corp_ID": "ZOHO",
            "Maker_ID": "M001",
            "Checker_ID": "C001",
            "Approver_ID": "A002"
          },
          "Body": {
            "Payment": [{
                "RefNo": "test1",
                "Amount": "100",
                "Debit_TrnParticulars": "AISHWARYA",
                "Debit_PartTrnRmks": "SESHADRI",
                "Ben_Acct_No": "1000110010002463",
                "Ben_TrnParticulars": "FTTEST",
                "Ben_PartTrnRmks": "ABHIJEET",
                "Mode_of_Pay": "FT",
                "Nature_of_Pay": "SALC",
                "Remarks": "DMR"
              },
              {
                "RefNo": "test10063",
                "Amount": "5",
                "Debit_Acct_No": "409000115190",
                "Debit_Acct_Name": "SACHIN R TENDULKAR",
                "Debit_IFSC": "RATN0000999",
                "Debit_Mobile": "9819378393",
                "Ben_IFSC": "UBIN0556688",
                "Ben_Acct_No": "8884476527",
                "Ben_Name": "Sudarshan",
                "Ben_BankName": "DHANALAXMI-Bank",
                "Ben_Email": "prabhat.deep1234567wearethebest@naturesports.co.in",
                "Ben_Mobile": "9696969696",
                "Mode_of_Pay": "IMPS",
                "Nature_of_Pay": "MPYMT",
                "Remarks": "IMPS REQUEST"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Signature": {
            "Signature": "1234"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


for (first in obj.corpAPIBankingReq.Body.Action_Body) {
console.log('First is:' + first);
if(first == 'doMultiPaymentCorpReq'){
console.log('yes');
} else {
console.log('no');
}
}
```